# Postgresql batch INSERT/UPDATE with externally provided IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table full of entities (people, companies, etc) that I need to merge updates with on a cron. Doing so in a batch is important as both datasets are arbitrarily large (I found one at a time would take years). Both ends come with an ExternalIdentifer (EXID) that I need to check. All the while, any INSERTs need to include an internal ID (integer) that is provided by my framework server. If necessary, I can guarantee that these IDs be sequential integers.

The logic is as follows:

- If the EXID exists, then just do a straight forward UPDATE on it.
- Else,

  - If EntityName exists, then do UPDATE Else, do an INSERT using an ID
    provided by framework server

Simplified table columns (please forgive my lack of formatting knowledge)

column_name | data_type

1. "entityname" | "character varying"
2. "externalidentifier" | "character varying"

The table being updated also has the internal ID provided by the framework:

3. "entityid" | "integer"

So the question boils down to, is there a quick way to do this in a batch using the IDs provided by the framework?

EDIT: This is being done via SQL executed from Java. I would prefer doing this mostly in SQL, but portions could be done in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this isn't that difficult to do in a number of statements. This solution can be done this way provided that the temporary table is under your control and isn't going to be modified during this transaction.

Short answer:
Essentially updates are done using the intersection of the two table. Then they are removed before moving on. After that is all done and only inserts are left. We grab some consecutive IDs from the framework, create a serial sequence starting at the starting ID and create a new serial key column for the IDs using that sequence.

```
-- Do this once to create sequence
create sequence erm.temporary_new_id;
```

SQL:

```
-- Update any that have matching externalidentifier
update erm.entity set 
entityname = up.entityname

from (select * from erm.temp_entity_import where externalidentifier in

(select externalidentifier from erm.entity
intersect
select externalidentifier from erm.temp_entity_import)) as up

where erm.entity.externalidentifier = up.externalidentifier;

-- Now remove those from the temp table and return the # of affected rows
with del as (delete from erm.temp_entity_import where externalidentifier in

(select externalidentifier from erm.entity
intersect
select externalidentifier from erm.temp_entity_import) returning true)
select count(*) as rowcount from del;

-- Update any with matching entityname
update erm.entity set 
externalidentifier = up.externalidentifier

from (select * from erm.temp_entity_import where entityname in

(select entityname from erm.entity
intersect
select entityname from erm.temp_entity_import)) as up

where erm.entity.entityname = up.entityname;

-- Now remove those from the temp table and return the # of affected rows
with del as (delete from erm.temp_entity_import where entityname in

(select entityname from erm.entity
intersect
select entityname from erm.temp_entity_import) returning true)
select count(*) as rowcount from del;

-- Grab the number of rows left as the number to be inserted so we know how many IDs to claim
select count(temp_entity_id) from erm.temp_entity_import;

-- Set the serial keygen to start at the id chunk we allocated and add the row
alter sequence erm.temporary_new_id restart with STARTING_ID_NUM;
alter table erm.temp_entity_import add column entityid integer default  nextval('erm.temporary_new_id');

-- Insert them all
insert into erm.entity (entityid, entityname, externalidentifier)
select t.entityid, t.entityname, t.externalidentifier
from erm.temp_entity_import as t;

-- Delete from temp table (we can just wipe it)
delete from erm.temp_entity_import;

-- Remove the id column for next time
alter table erm.temp_entity_import drop column entityid;
```